# How only allow NFT minting after course completion

Tags: blockchain, nft, erc-721, openzeppelin, erc-1155

I am new to ethereum I building a course page where you would get an NFT if you complete the course. Any idea on how to implement it.

Comment: Is the course about learning how to mint NFTs?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have mapping to get track of whether an address is completed the course or not eg: `mapping(address => bool) public isCompleted`
you can updtae this mapping if specefic address completed the course.

you also need a function called `getReward` then in the function you should check the mapping, you can implement it like this :

```
function getreward() public{
    bool courseCompleted = isCompleted[msg.sender];
    require(courseCompleted,"not completed the course");

    // if require get passed then the code to transfer or mint the NFT goes here
}
```